# How to combine a surface and quiver plot in python in one plot

Tags: python, plot, vector, surface

I have the following code that produces me one surface plot with a surface given as the z-coordinate with respect to a meshgrid X,Y.

This code also produces a vector field plot, as a separate figure with respect to the same coordinate system X,Y.

Is there a way for me to combine these two figures in one? Have the vector field either on the surface or at the bottom of the surface plot?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import grad_field
 # first create the plot of the elevation surface
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
LNG = np.linspace(lngmin,lngmax,samples1)
LAT = np.linspace(latmin,latmax, samples2)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(LNG,LAT)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, elev_mat)
plt.show()
 
# now create the vector field plot of the gradients
[gradx,grady] = grad_field.grad_field(elev_mat)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Arrows scale with plot width, not view')
ax1.quiver(X, Y, gradx, grady, units='xy' ,scale=2, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple plots next/below each other via `plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)`. Take a look at the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) for examples.

If you want to create multiple plots in one, you could share the x or y axis via `ax.twinx()` or `ax.twiny()`.